# How to generate a random number within a range in D

Tags: random, d

How do i generate a random number within a range in D?

```
int number = randomNumber(0,1);
```

Something like this. So `number` would be equal to either `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int number = uniform!"[]"(0,1);
```

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_random.html#.uniform

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer, but one question. What does the   !"[]"   do? Looked like you could write it like this: int number = uniform(0,1);

Comment: It means a closed interval while the default is a half-open interval (first boundary is inclusive and second is exclusive)